# User Story based deployments ( TFS API merge automation )

Tags: deployment, tfs

As a team we are following Agile/scrum methodology with 2 weeks sprint cycle. Instead of deploying an aggregate of sprint work every 2 weeks, we want to move forward with a one-click solution that deploys changes per user story.

For discussion sake, we have two branches Dev and QA. Once a user story is marked ready to deploy, I merge it's changesets into QA branch and the deployment package gets generated from that branch as the build triggers.

I wrote the code to automate the merge process integrating with TFS API. The challenge I am having here is dealing with changes in source control when there are dependencies. Example below.

```
Changeset   UserStory#

100         1  (File1.cs, File2.cs)
101         2  (File2.cs)
102         1  (File2.cs)
```

In the scenario above, if I have Story1 marked ready for deployment, and the merge program triggers to merge, I see that I can't merge because changeset 102 has changes in File2.cs for story2 that is not ready to deploy. Even if story2 is ready to deploy, I have to merge 100,  101 and 102 in order. But programming to code re-ordering what changesets to merge what I find as look at the history gets a bit more tricky if you consider several check-in's

Any suggesstions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe you can do this with out of box functionality, but these 2 links may be of interest.

http://selagroup.com/Wimbi
http://mergeworkitems.codeplex.com/